# Old .Net app crashed. What does this event log info mean?

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, event-log

A .NET application running in one of our systems 24/7 suddenly crashed without logging any errors.

The only error information we were able to retrieve is in the windows events log, with this codes:

```
faulting module msvcr80.dll, 
version 8.0.50727.3053, 
stamp 4889d619, 
debug? 0, 
fault address 0x000144dc.
```

Has anyone experienced an issue like this before? Does anybody have an idea of what the location in the ms library is about or where to find such information? Where can I start in trying to resolve this issue?

**Edit:** the application wasn't changed recently and every error should be trapped and logged, so the behavior seems really strange. What I really wanted to know is what function is located at the given offset, so that maybe we can figure out where the crash happened.

Comment: Has it crashed before? How often does it crash?

Comment: Are you sure the event log entry is related? If so, then presumably the app does p/invoke or is a mixed mode assembly?

Comment: Could be a million things - does it crash randomly?  When you're doing something specific?  On a certain O/S only?  You say 'suddenly' - are you absolutely positively 100% sure that the only thing that changed was the date/time?  And at what date/time did it suddenly start crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it seems like it's anti-virus or update related, but it really could just be just a fluke, or a sign of failing hardware. I would setup process monitor and log in detail what the application's doing if it happens again. If this is a onetime occurrence I wouldn't worry about it much.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: As the other guys' answers made good points, none were on the mark. As nothing has changed on the server, I'll put it down to this: http://www.newscientist.com/blog/technology/2008/03/do-we-need-cosmic-ray-alerts-for.html. I've accepted this for the suggestion "If this is a onetime occurrence I wouldn't worry about it much"

Answer (score 3):

That's the C++ runtime library (from 2005 I think).

It can be flagged as being the cause for many things, from malware attacks to C++ code losing access to databases to actual program bugs. Generally when exceptions are not handled.

The main point here though is that if all has been running okay and it has suddenly been flagged then I would look to see what changed on the system on which it is used to cause the crash.

Only by making it occur again will you be able to track down what code actually caused the crash.

**edit**

Check for any updates put onto the machine recently for any of the software. Not just yours, but Microsoft, antivirus, etc. It is possible thta one of these is the culprit. I know someone who had been using Office 2000 quite happily until a recent update for AVG overwrote the C runtime dll and he could no longer print anything or receive emails.

I know that its not ideal but you will probably have to pass this onto Microsoft as it is buried within their DLL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've updated the question if you could take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If its *24/7* and *suddenly crashed*; I would ask about changes/updates in the system that were made in the recent past.

The file `msvcr80.dll` is a Visual Studio 2005 VC++ Runtime library; doesn't help much in digging the exact cause.

[This discussion](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaprograms/thread/e5e1ae2f-f109-4bde-af20-ebcb7244fb5c) might help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've updated the question if you could take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @DaveDev: I meant, change in the System/OS; It seems some security updates/patches were added recently.

Comment: Someone probably installed windows updates or another app which updated the C++ runtime.